# AJAX Request getContent Laravel 5.1

Tags: ajax, laravel

[image: AJAX RETURN]

```
$content = $request->getContent();
   return \Response::json([
                'success' =>  $content
            ]);
```

I don't know how to format it to json in laravel 5.1. I want to use the data but if I use $request->input('name') it is null, it's actually in the controller. If you have another way to get the data it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of putting the content to that success key? Can you please explain what you want?

Comment: The point is to see if the request gets the data. How to format it in php or laravel?

Comment: You can try, `$request->all()` to see whats inside, not `getContent`

Comment: $request->input('name') is empty and $request->all() is also empty but $content = $request->getContent(); I can see the data but the problem is I don't know how to parse it in php or laravel.  I did use this one http_parse_headers($content) but I get this error Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\http_parse_headers()

Comment: it means that there is no such function. Can you provide the code of your form?

Answer (score 0):

you would have to parse the response in the client-side:

```
JSON.parse(ajaxResponse)
```

right now you're only getting a string back from the server

Comment: I want to get every data send from a form and I want to parse it in php or laravel in json format.

Comment: when a request is sent to the server, you can get the data in that request using `$request->all()` which will be in array format. after that you can just use php's `json_encode` to save the data in json format

Comment: $request->input('name') is empty and $request->all() is also empty but $content = $request->getContent(); I can see the data but the problem is I don't know how to parse it in php or laravel.

Comment: I did use this one http_parse_headers($content) but I get this error Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\http_parse_headers()

Comment: you need to show us the rest of the code, because afaik neither `Illuminate\Http\Request` nor `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` have a `getContent()` method